# How can use scipy with a datetime without the right formatting?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to visualise a dataset and its average with scipy.interpolate and matplotlb.
But when im trying to run the code that should work perfectly fine it gives me the error:

```
  File "mittel.py", line 19, in <module>
    p1 = polyfit(x, y, 1)
  File "C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 589, in polyfit
    x = NX.asarray(x) + 0.0
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

And the code is:

```
import time as ti
import pandas as pd 
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import csv
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from scipy.interpolate import * 

data = pd.read_csv("includes\\csv.csv")

x = array(data["day"])
y = array(data["balance"])

p1 = polyfit(x, y, 1)

print(p1)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.plot(x, polyval(p1, x), "-r")

plt.show()
```

I have already tried to convert the x array to a string with

```
x = str(x)
```

but that didnt help at all.

My csv file looks like this:

```
balance,day

242537,28-5
246362,29-5
246659,30-5
246844,31-5
```

Do you know why that error accurs?

Comment: `"28-5"` is not a number you can perform calculations with. So you first need to convert this to a valid date (it's lacking a year also). From a date you can convert to a numerical representation. Once you have numbers you can do fitting.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> x = NX.asarray(x) + 0.0
> ```
>
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

As you can see here, `+` is interpreted to concatenate two strings, whereas you need to add float. So instead of converting x to a string object, try converting x to a float object:

```
x = float(array(data["day"]))
y = float(array(data["balance"]))
```

Comment: okay thanks, but know its telling ,me that, only size-1 arrays can be converted into python scalaras.